# Opencv remove unwanted part of an image

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to detect some meter reading of an analogue meter. I am currently using the amazon recognition service to extract readings from a meter in a react-native app. The process did not work very well so as part of trying to fix this. I implemented a cropping functionality in the app so we send only relevant part of the image to the service. I run into another problem. The analogue separators on the meter are interspersed such that they are read as ones.

uncroppped meter image
[uncroppped meter image](https://i.imgur.com/yWb3N0r.jpg)

cropped image from the mobile app
[cropped image from the mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQwdD.png)

What I have tried. I created a simple server application to try to remove these lines before we send the image to rekognito

- Converted the image to greyscale
- Applied Gaussian blur to remove some of the noise.
- Applied the [canny algortihm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) to detect the edges.

[using opencv for node](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs#readme)

```
const { img } = req.params; // Mat

  const grayWithGaussianBlur = img
    .cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    .gaussianBlur(new cv.Size(5, 5), 0, 0, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    .canny(30, 150);
```

The result look like this.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGwxD.jpg)

The output is as I expect. I have been trying to figure out how to remove the interspersed edges leaving the clearly defined edge.

I filtered the contours only leaving contours that meet specific criteria. Like area greater than a certain threshold,

```
 const contours = grayWithGaussianBlur.copy().findContours(cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

  const viable = contours.filter(contour => {
     const { width,height } = contour.boundingRect();
     return width > 5 && width <= height; // example criteria
  });

  const newImage = new cv.Mat(grayWithGaussianBlur.rows, grayWithGaussianBlur.cols, 0);

  newImage.drawContours(viable, new cv.Vec3(255, 255, 255), -1);
```

Can't get this to work.

My understanding of image processing concepts are very vague and I am unsure of this is a good way to fix this problem. I also don't know much about what I am doing :).

Sorry, I don't have enough reputations to embed the images directly.

Can anyone help or suggest a better approach to removing the lines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a database of meter types. then identify the meter type and use the stored digit locations. at least that's how I would go about this problem. it doesn't make sense to create a wonder machine that can macically read everything.

Comment: "The analogue separators on the meter are interspersed such that they are read as ones."  Does this occur 100% of the time? Can't you just drop every other digit and be done?

Comment: @Piglet thanks for the suggestion. It is rather very important to me that I detect to the highest accuracy the digits on the image. It would be nice to detect the reading of the meter values with an ocr. But what I want to do is help it out a little by removing the extra lines. I don't understand how a database of meter types will help. I have only one meter type :)

Comment: @Jeff for this meter yes 80% of the time. I have traces of 1 at the odd position thus

1x1x1x100  if it makes sense.  I tried removing this in code. as in remove every odd number in the reading if it is a one. But It seem to be different for every picture. a lot of edge cases

Comment: if you have only one meter type then you can simpyl use a concept called AOI (area of interest) or ROI (region of interest)
I mean you know exactly where to find the digits on your meter right? just crop the digtis from your image

Comment: AOI interesting @Piglet. That would work nicely  I think. I will read more on the subject thank you very much

Comment: you can either use a fixed setup or you have to detect let's say the blue mask on the meter front to align everything.

Comment: seems reasonable. I have a lot of reading to do if I can implement any of these ideas @Piglet

Comment: @Piglet I think something can potentially work but after a lot of research. When i apply a threshold to the image. I get those separators standing out vividly. Could you help me detect and remove those blocks of pixels